# Android AsyncTask - doInBackground not running

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm attempting to use an AsyncTask to make an HTTP request and get back some JSON, but for some reason the doInBackground method of my Async task is never running.
I've seen a few solutions on SO for this issue but none seemed to help - I've also tried using a regular thread instead of Async Task but it seemed to have a similar problem.

My fragment class which contains the AsyncTask class:

```
public class ChallengeListFragment extends ListFragment {

    ...

    private ArrayList<Challenge> mChallenges;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.challenges_list_fragment_title);
        mChallenges = new ArrayList<Challenge>();


        new JSONRetriever().execute("URL_HERE");

        ...
    }


    // Async Task class to perform HTTP requests in a separate thread:
    private class JSONRetriever extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{

        JSONArray challengesJsonArray;
        JSONObject challengesJsonObject;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPreExecute()!!!");
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {
            challengesJsonObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url[0]);
            return challengesJsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
           super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
           Log.i(LOG_TAG, jsonObject.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

...and my JSONParser class, taken from a commonly used guide or answer:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

I have stepped through the program several times and while onPreExecute() runs, doInBackground() never runs. I am not running any other Async Tasks while this is happening or anything like that.

Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks.

**Update:**
Following advice in the comments I tried removing the code in doInBackground() and putting a log statement in there instead and it seems it is in fact running, despite the method never seeming to be entered when I stepped through the program.

The full LogCat when this happens is:

```
850-850/com.ethanml.proveit I/PROVEIT﹕ onPreExecute()!!!
12-08 19:01:45.952      850-850/com.ethanml.proveit D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-08 19:01:45.952      850-878/com.ethanml.proveit D/PROVEIT﹕ DO IN BACKGROUND
12-08 19:01:45.962      850-850/com.ethanml.proveit W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-08 19:01:45.992      850-850/com.ethanml.proveit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ethanml.proveit/com.ethanml.proveit.ChallengeListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ethanml.proveit.ChallengeListFragment.onCreate(ChallengeListFragment.java:55)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1673)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:854)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The NPE on ChallengeListFragment at line 55 referred to in the log refers to a for loop I'm using to step through the JSON array which is supposed to be populated within the Async Task's onPostExecute - since this seems to never get executed, the JSONArray is null and the program crashes.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't run? did you try calling `Log.e()` inside `doInBackground()` before returning? Are you sure there is no `Exception` being thrown by `getJSONFromUrl()`?

Comment: As Emmanuel told you, You need to remove the code inside doInBackground() and just use Log.d then check if your log message is printed or not when you run  your app.

Comment: OK looks like you were right after all, the debug log did in fact work...but when I debugged and stepped through it manually before it never entered the method :S 
Does that mean you guys know what this is likely to be then?

Comment: Here is the LogCat log between onPreExecute and doInBackground():

12-08 19:07:45.832      945-945/com.ethanml.proveit D/DEBUG﹕ onPreExecute()!!!
12-08 19:07:45.852      945-945/com.ethanml.proveit D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-08 19:07:45.852      945-945/com.ethanml.proveit W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-08 19:07:45.872      945-968/com.ethanml.proveit D/DEBUG﹕ !!! DO IN BACKGROUND !!!

...which is followed by a NullPointerException referring to the for loop in the code above which loops through the (unassigned) JSONArray.

Comment: Now that you know doInBackground is geting called try to put logs in get getJSONFromUrl function and find out whether request is send successfully or not

Comment: Hi, I did as you said but it seems the getJSONFromUrl function is never entered as there is no sign of the log.
I get log messages from onPreExecute, then doInBackground, and then the NullPointerException for the for loop which shouldn't come until after all the JSONParser stuff has been called =/

Comment: Scratch that, stupid mistake, the JSON parser is being run after all, I've narrowed it down to the point where I can see the problem is to do with the 'main' thread continuing before my Async Task has finished getting and returning the data needed by the main thread for it to display anything.
So, while the app no longer crashes, my ListFragment is a blank list because it displays before its array is populated by the Async Task!
Is there something I'm missing regarding using threads properly in this case?